# swift_message insert object into setBody

Tags: php, symfony, object, swiftmailer

I have an object in which I would like to insert into my setBody.

Object:

```
   {
      "v1":
        {"name":"n1","price":10},
      "v2":
        {"name":"n2","price":20}
    }
```

What I want:

```
<p>name: n1, price: 10</p>
<p>name: n2, price: 20</p>
```

My code (not correct):

```
$message->setBody(
  '...' .
    foreach (products as $key => $value) {
      <p>name: $value->name, price: $value->price</p>
    }
  .'...', 'text/html');
```

Comment: And what is your polite question?

Comment: My code is not correct.

Comment: You give a foreach loop as function attribute ... :-/

Comment: Should be done before `setBody` and with syntax `"<p>name:".$value->name.", price:".$value->price."</p>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that is excactly what you are asking, but here is the correct syntax:

```
$myText = "";
foreach (products as $key => $value) {
    $myText .= "<p>name:".$value->name.", price:".$value->price."</p>";
}

$message->setBody(
  '...'.$myText.'...',
 'text/html');
```